# Ruby on Rails Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to connect my website to a style sheet in Ruby on Rails but I don't know how to . I have a stylesheet in my application.html.erb file but I don't know how to get to it or what the name of it is . I do have a pages.scss but when I put in css it doesn't show the changes on my website . Can someone help ?

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AucIt</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">    
<h1>AucIt</h1>

 <nav>  

  <ul>
   <li style="font-size: 20px"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
   <li style="font-size:20px"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
   <li style="font-size:20px"><a href="#">List</a></li>

</ul>

</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check whether you have added pages.scss in default.css ?

```
 *= require pages
```

If you are running your server in production mode, don't forget to run command

> `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Where is default.css

Comment: If it has been created, it would be in `your-rails-app-name/app/assets/stylesheets` ... if it's not created, you need to.

Comment: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`  you have added default.css by using this line. So, check your app/assets/stylesheets folder. default.css will be there

Comment: @craig.kaminsky in there I only have application.css and pages.scss

Comment: @ShefaleeChaudhary I don't have a default.css should I add it ?

Comment: My sense is that you will want to change `'default'` to `'application`' in that line (`stylesheet_link_tag`, that is)

Comment: does it connect to application.css ?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you say you don't know where that file is, I think you've mistakenly put `default` instead of `application` for the name of your css file. Otherwise you would know where it is because you created it.

change this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

And then so long as you have a pages.scss at `app/assets/stylesheets/pages.scss` make sure you add the following in your application.css file (which is located at `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`)

```
*= require "pages"
*= require_self
*/
```

Comment: But I don't know where application is either .

Comment: I just told you. It's in app/assets/stylesheet/application.css

Comment: But the styles that I put in my css file aren't showing up on my website